# Distance on robot

Tags: python, robotics

I created a `robot` that will run based on `python`. For its autonomous program I need it to run for a certain distance( say 10 feet). Currently I am using time to have it go the distance, but is there any way to implement distance in the code to make it more exact. Thank you.

This was code for an old robotics competition i did and i want to learn by improving it. I used these libraries:

```
import sys
import wpilib
import logging
from time import time
```

This is the code:

```
def autonomous_straight(self):
    '''Called when autonomous mode is enabled'''

    t0 = time()

    slow_forward = 0.25

    t_forward_time = 6.5
    t_spin_time = 11
    t_shoot_time = 11.5


    while self.isAutonomous() and self.isEnabled():
        t = time() - t0

        if t < t_forward_time:

            self.motor_left.set(slow_forward)
            self.motor_right.set(-slow_forward)
            self.motor_gobbler.set(1.0)

        elif t < t_spin_time:
            self.motor_left.set(2 * slow_forward)
            self.motor_right.set(2 * slow_forward)
            self.motor_shooter.set(-1.0)

        elif t < t_shoot_time:
            self.motor_mooover.set(.5)

        else:
            self.full_stop()
            self.motor_gear.set(-1.0)

        wpilib.Timer.delay(0.01)

    self.full_stop()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're currently using?

Comment: Is this an actual physical robot or just a simulation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share what libraries you are using and what you are using to interface with hardware? Also consider listing the sensors available to the control program. Really not enough detail here to provide much help.

Comment: Which parameters (wrt the robot's movement) do you have control over?

Comment: its an actual physical robot

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to drive a distance based on time.  While this may work over short distances at known speeds, it's generally much better to drive based on sensor feedback.  What you're going to want to take a look at are `encoders`, more specifically Rotary encoders.  Encoders are simply counters that keep track of 'ticks'.  Each 'tick' represents a percent rotation of the drive shaft.

[image: formula]

where `d` is distance traveled, `cir` is the wheel circumference `res` is the encoder 'resolution' (number of ticks per rotation), and `num` is the current tick count (read off the encoder)

```
# Example Implementation
import wpilib
import math

# Some dummy speed controllers
leftSpeed = wpilib.Spark(0)
rightSpeed = wpilib.Spark(1)

# Create a new encoder linked to DIO pins 0 & 1
encoder = wpilib.Encoder(0, 1)

# Transform ticks into distance traveled
# Assuming 6" wheels, 512 resolution
def travelDist (ticks):
  return ((math.pi * 6) / 512) * ticks

# Define auto, takes travel distance in inches
def drive_for(dist = 10):
  while travelDist(encoder.get()) < dist:
    rightSpeed.set(1)
    leftSpeed.set(-1)  # negative because one controller must be inverted
```

This simple implementation will allow you to call `drive_for(dist)` to travel a desired distance with a fair degree of accuracy.  It does however, have quite a few problems.  Here we attempt to set a *linear* speed, notice there is no acceleration control.  This will cause error to build up over longer distances, the solution to this is PID control.  wpilib has constructs to simplify the math. Simply take the difference between your setpoint and current travel distance and plug it into your PID controller as an error.  The PID controller will spit out a new value to set your motor controllers to.  The PID controller (with some tuning) can account for acceleration, inertia, and overshoot.

docs on PID:
http://robotpy.readthedocs.io/projects/wpilib/en/latest/_modules/wpilib/pidcontroller.html?